# Is my proof that product of Cauchy sequences is Cauchy, correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences, rational-numbers, quantifiers

What I am trying to prove is the following:

> Let $(a_i)_{i = 1}^\infty$ and $(b_i)_{i = 1}^\infty$ be Cauchy sequences of rationals. Then the sequence $(a_ib_i)_{i = 1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals.

My attempt at proving it is as follows.

Let $\varepsilon, \delta>0$ be rationals. Now, there exists an $N\ge 1$ such that for all $i, j\ge N$, we have $\lvert a_i-a_j\rvert, \lvert b_i-b_j\rvert\le\delta$. Also, since Cauchy sequences are bounded, there exists a rational $M\ge \delta$ such that for each $i\ge 1$, we have $\lvert a_i\rvert, \lvert b_i\rvert\le M$.
Let $i, j\ge N$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lvert a_ib_i-a_jb_j\rvert&\le\delta\lvert b_i\rvert+\delta\lvert a_i\rvert+\delta^2\\
&\le\delta(2M+\delta)\\
&\le3M\delta.
\end{align*}
Now, $3M\delta<\varepsilon\impliedby\delta<\varepsilon/(3M)$ since $M>0$. But there does exist a rational $\tilde\delta$ such that $0<\tilde\delta<\varepsilon/(3M)$. Hence we are done.

---

Is my proof correct? I am in doubt because I am confused by the quantifiers.

Note that in the above I am using the result that if $x, y, z, w$ are rationals such that $\lvert x-y\rvert\le\varepsilon$ and $\lvert w-z\rvert\le\delta$, then we have $\lvert xz-yw\rvert\le\varepsilon\lvert z\rvert+\delta\lvert x\rvert+\varepsilon\delta$, which has already been proven before in the text I'm following.

---

**Question:** In order for the above proof to work, doesn't one also need to ensure that $\tilde\delta\le M$?

Comment: How do you justify the inequality $\lvert a_ib_i-a_jb_j\rvert \le\delta\lvert a_i\rvert+\delta\lvert a_j\rvert+\delta^2$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have shown that $\lvert xz-yw\rvert\le\varepsilon\lvert z\rvert+\delta\lvert x\rvert+\varepsilon\delta$ if $\lvert x-y\rvert\le \varepsilon$ and $\lvert z-w\rvert\le\delta$.

Comment: How did you get this?

Comment: @Anon I am following Tao, and he has shown this for rationals before this result.

Comment: Then the proof looks OK. Unconventional but providing the result holds as you say then yes.

Comment: @Anon I don't think that the proof as presented is correct. One also needs to ensure that $\tilde\delta\le M$.

Answer (score 5):

You can write $a_ib_i-a_jb_j$ as $a_i(b_i-b_j)+b_j(a_i-a_j) $
So $$|a_i b_i - a_jb_j | \leq |a_i ||b_i-b_j|+ |b_j||a_i-a_j|$$ then you can just use the fact that Cauchy sequences are bounded.

Comment: This is a nice alternative approach. But it doesn't answer if my proof is correct.

Comment: I would say this is the conventional way to do it.  This has many generalizations to related proofs.

Comment: @GEdgar Noted. But I would still like to know if my original way works. :)